# Compressing images - get image size PHP

Tags: php, compression, flush

I have a script that recursively loops through all the sub directories and compresses all the jpegs. I print the file size, before and after the compression but it prints the same number.
The script I am running is:

```
set_time_limit (86000);
ob_implicit_flush(true);
$main = "files";

function readDirs($main){
  $dirHandle = opendir($main);
  while($file = readdir($dirHandle)){
    $newFile = $main.'/'.$file;
    if(is_dir($newFile) && $file != '.' && $file != '..'){
       readDirs($newFile);
    }
    else{
        if($file != '.' && $file != '..' && stristr($newFile,'.jpg'))
        {
            //echo $newFile.'</br>';
            $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($newFile);
            echo 'Compressing '.$newFile.'... from ('.filesize($newFile).' bytes) to (';
            imagejpeg($img,$newFile, 30);
            echo filesize($newFile).' bytes)...<br>';
            for($k = 0; $k < 40000; $k++)
                echo ' '; // extra spaces to fill up browser buffer
        }
    }
  } 
}
```

And the output I get is:

> Compressing
>   files/1013/0079/3180/Beautifully_renovated_garden_apartment_in_Rehavia_7.JPG...
>   from (58666 bytes) to (58666 bytes)... Compressing
>   files/1013/0088/0559/Exquisite_stand_alone_house_in_Givat_Hamivtar_exceptional_views_3.JPG...
>   from (49786 bytes) to (49786 bytes)... Compressing
>   files/1013/0088/0587/Exquisite_stand_alone_house_in_Givat_Hamivtar_exceptional_views_6.JPG...
>   from (18994 bytes) to (18994 bytes)... Compressing
>   files/1013/0138/4914/Beautiful_4_rooms_apartment_with_views_to_the_Old_City_2.JPG...
>   from (527801 bytes) to (527801 bytes)... Compressing
>   files/1013/0208/0656/Fevrier_2011_005.JPG... from (35607 bytes) to
>   (35607 bytes)... Compressing
>   files/1013/0216/6078/Beautiful_townhouse_in_the_heart_of_the_German_Colony_00.JPG...
>   from (42509 bytes) to (42509 bytes)... Compressing
>   files/1013/0217/1359/Unique_luxurious_new_penthouse_in_the_heart_of_the_German_Colony_028.jpg...
>   from (1101251 bytes) to (1101251 bytes)... Compressing
>   files/1013/0269/0299/Exclusive_Duplex_Penthouse_in_the_German_Colony_0171.jpg...
>   from (20912 bytes) to (20912 bytes)... Compressing
>   files/1013/0821/0299/Beautiful_views_to_the_Knesset_and_Gan_Saker_016.JPG...
>   from (570428 bytes) to (570428 bytes)... Compressing
>   files/1013/0822/0660/Beautiful_new_penthouse_in_luxurious_building_with_pool_158double.jpg...
>   from (1020561 bytes) to (1020561 bytes)... Compressing
>   files/1013/0847/8190/New_luxurious_penthouse_with_private_entrance_in_Old_Katamon_016.JPG...
>   from (542071 bytes) to (542071 bytes)... ... ... ...

Can someone tell me what problem is? Why is the size not updating?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try doing a `clearstatcache()` in between the two filesize calls

Comment: Jerusalem has a German Colony? Interesting. (ah, and from the 19th century no less! There goes my lunch break reading Wikipedia. Boy, I'd love to own that townhouse. Or the penthouse! *drool*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filesize()` uses a caching mechanism (the "stat cache") that may not have enough time to refresh in between the two calls.

Use `clearstatcache()` to force the cache to refresh.

Answer (score 1):

The filesize() function caches the size for every file to prevent stat()-syscalls which are quite slow.
It holds internally the filesize for the given filename to respond faster on new calls.

As suggested you have to call clearstatcache() to get the right results.
If you're using PHP >= 5.3.0 you can also specify the part of the cache that has to be cleared.

You're code should then look like this:

```
        echo 'Compressing '.$newFile.'... from ('.filesize($newFile).' bytes) to (';
        imagejpeg($img,$newFile, 30);
        clearstatcache(true, $newFile);  // or clearstatcache() if you want to flush the whole cache
        echo filesize($newFile).' bytes)...<br>';
```

I hope this is what you're looking for.